# Prove variation of Titchsmarsh convolution theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

I want to prove the following statement. Let
$$
f,\,g\in L_1(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Also
$$
\forall x<0 \quad f(x)=g(x)=0
$$
and
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f*g=0,
$$
where $*$ denotes a convolution. **Then** $f\equiv0$ or $g\equiv0$ almost everywhere.

It is advised to prove it using Fourier transform. I have read through this question: [convolution of non-zero functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024340/convolution-of-non-zero-functions), but I can't figure it out if I can apply this techinque to my problem, because I don't have compact support.

*As advised in the comments, I note that this variation should be proved without the application of Titchsmarsh theorem.*

Comment: reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem it seems like your variation follows from it, have you tried that?

Comment: @supinf yes, but then I have to prove the theorem itself.

Comment: ok i understand. Maybe you should add to your question that you are not allowed to use that theorem itself

Comment: @supinf edited the question

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma** *If convolution of two finite functions is zero, then one of these functions is zero almost everywhere.*

*Proof. Can be found here [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024340/convolution-of-non-zero-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024340/convolution-of-non-zero-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1_)*

Now take an arbitrary $A>0$ and assume
$$
f_A=f\cdot\chi_{[0;A]} 
$$
and 
$$
g_A=g\cdot\chi_{[0;A]} 
$$
Observe that for $y\leq A$
$$
0=f*g(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)g(y-x)\;dx=\int_{0}^{y}f(x)g(y-x)\;dx=\int_{0}^{y}f_A(x)g_A(y-x)\;dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_A(x)g_A(y-x)\;dx=f_A*g_A(y).
$$
Thus, $f_A$ or $g_A$ is zero almost everywhere (apply the Lemma), meaning that $f$ or $g$ is almost everywhere zero on every interval, therefore, it vanishes almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.